# Forwarding email

Tags: email, email-forwarding

I currently own a domain through Go Daddy and my website for my business is through google sites. I am getting ready to close my business but want to keep my email, due to another business I receive emails about. My email is @sportshealthandwellness, which is the domain I currently own but want to close. Is it possible to NOT renew my domain, but forward my @sportshealthandwellness emails to my gmail?

Comment: This is something you need to arrange with your email hosting provider to either forward the messages to your new address.

Comment: @ale Even then, she needs to keep the domain.

Comment: True. This isn't really a web apps question, though.

Answer (score 2):

No. Owning an email from a domain requires that you own a domain. This is because email requires DNS records that require the purchasing of that domain. You may however just use the domain registration service without web hosting.